# How to include BIT type column in SELECT part with out including it on the GROUP BY in T-SQL?

Tags: sql, t-sql, group-by, aggregate

Here is my T-SQL query

```
SELECT 
    ProductID,
    VendorID,
    ProductName= MAX(ProductName),
    VendorName = MAX(VendorName),
    IsActive = MAX(IsActive) # This brings error 
FROM ProductVendorAssoc 
GROUP BY  
    ProductID,
    VendorID
```

I want to apply `GROUP BY` only for the `ProductID and VendorID` fields, but need to populate the `ProductID, VendorID, ProductName, VendorName, IsActive` fields.

Here I used the agreggate function `MAX(ProductName)` to avoid `ProductName` in the group by list.

But the same trick is not working for `BIT` columns as operand data type bit is invalid for max operator.

How can i include `BIT` type column in `SELEC`T part with out including it on the `GROUP BY`?

**Update.**

What should I need to do if i need to include an `INT` column like `UserID` in `SELECT` in the same way

Comment: It is SQL Server 2008, but i need to wok it on 2005 too

Comment: @marc_s i omitted that part of query from the question

Answer (score 116, accepted):

Put a CASE expression in there, or convert it to int:

```
IsActive = MAX(CASE WHEN IsActive=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

or,

```
IsActive = MAX(CONVERT(int,IsActive))
```

You should also be aware, obviously, that this means that the values in the ProductName, VendorName and IsActive columns in the result set may all come from different rows in the base table.

---

If you want those three columns to actually all be from the same row (and assuming SQL Server 2005 or later), you'd do something like:

```
;With Numbered as (
    SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
        PARTITION BY ProductID,VendorID
        ORDER BY /* Something appropriate, or if we just want random... */ newid()) as rn
    FROM ProductVendorAssoc
)
select
    ProductID,
    VendorID,
    ProductName,
    VendorName,
    IsActive
FROM Numbered where rn=1
```

Comment: What should I need to do if i need to include an INT column like UserID in SELECT in the same way

Comment: @Mithun P - just the same, you can take the `MAX` on that column (with the same disclaimer), or switch to the other style of statement I've shown.

Comment: should the line `SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (` have "`rn = `" added to it? Like this:  `SELECT *,rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (`

Comment: @WillNewton - there's two ways to associate an alias - `alias = expression` or `expression as alias` - I've used the second form, but it's scrolled over to the right.

Comment: How about Indexed views? As we cannot use MAX() in the indexed views, is there a way to handle it in the indexed views?

Comment: @HariKrishnaGaddipati - in the indexed view, have a `SUM` and `COUNT_BIG`, then wrap a non-indexed view atop that that checks that the sum isn't `0`, I *think*.

Answer (score 16):

Shorter way to do this:

```
IsActive = MAX(0+IsActive)
```

Comment: Implicit type conversion?

Answer (score 4):

In SQL2005/2008 this would be look like this:

```
select ProductId, VendorId, ProductName, VendorName, IsActive
from
(
    select *, row_number() over (partition by ProductId, VendorId order by ProductId) RowNumber
    from Production.Product
) tt
where RowNumber = 1
```